# Error Undefined variable: siteConfig APP/views/elements/header.ctp, line 9

Tags: cakephp

Tenho um com problema para carregar imagens num projeto que usa CakePHP 1.3.15.
O link abaixo mostra o que está ocorrendo.
http://curia.mitrarj.org.br/files/images/list_type_5/_DSC9589_16022016124709.jpg

Segue o código referente ao erro:

```
<a href="<?php echo URL; ?>">
            <img src="<?php echo URL; ?>img/logos/<?php echo $siteConfig['Configuration']['logo_path_color'] ?>/headerLogo.png" alt="" title="" />
        </a>
```

O Código do meu app_controller

```
<?php  
class AppController extends Controller
{
    var $uses = array(
        'Administrator',
        'AdminMenu',
        'ArticleInterview',
        'ArticleInterviewListType',
        'ArticleInterviewTag',
        'Author',
        'BitlyLink',
        'City',
        'Comment',
        'Church',
        'Configuration',
        'Contact', 
        'Country',
        'ErrorPage',
        'Event',
        'EventType',
        'EventListType',
        'EventTag',
        'Feature',
        'FeatureConfiguration',
        'Gallery',
        'GalleryImage',
        'MediaLibrary',
        'Member',
        'News',
        'NewsListType',
        'NewsTag',
        'Page',
        'PageCategory',
        'PageTag',
        'PostMedia',
        'Revision',
        'State',
        'Saint',
        'SaintTag',
        'Tag',
        'User',
        'Utility',
        'ViewClick',
        'PostCategory',
        'PostCategoryTag',
        'Bishop',
        'EventBishop',
        'Birthday',
        'SatisfactionSurvey',
        'DailyLiturgy',
        'Music',
        'MusicsListType',
        'MusicsTag'
    );

    var $helpers = array(
        'Excel', 
        'Facebook', 
        'Form', 
        'Html', 
        'ImageCache', 
        'ImageFn', 
        'Javascript', 
        'Menu', 
        'NumberFn', 
        'Session', 
        'Text', 
        'TextFn', 
        'Time', 
        'TimeFn', 
        'Translate', 
        'ViewFn', 
        'Youtube',
        'Xml',
    );

    var $components = array(
        'Bitly', 
        'Cep', 
        'PaymentReturns', 
        'Auth', 
        'Checkout',
        'ControllerList', 
        'Email', 
        'Facebook', 
        'Notifications',
        'Paypal',
        'RequestHandler',
        'Session', 
        'Twitter', 
        'Upload', 
        'Utility',
    );

    function beforeFilter()
    {

        parent::beforeFilter();

        // Remove www da URL para não dar problema de sessão
        if (!(strpos($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'], 'www') === false)) {
            $this->redirect(URL .  $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
        }

        Security::SetHash('md5');
        $this->_setCookie();
        Configure::write('UseCdnHost', false);


        if ($this->_isAdmin()) 
        {
            $this->set('site_config', $this->Configuration->findById(1));
            $this->layout = 'admin_default';
            //Criando variaveis globais e arquivos nescessarios
            if( isset( $this->params['form'] ) && !empty( $this->params['form'] ) )
            {
                $form_data = $this->processAjaxFormData( $this->params['form'] );
                if( !empty( $form_data ) )
                {
                    $this->data = $form_data;
                }
            } 

            if ( !isset( $this->bound_actions ) )
            {
                $this->bound_actions = array();
            }
            $this->_createDefaultArchives( $this->params['controller'] );

            $this->Auth->loginError = __("Login inválido.", true); 
            $this->Auth->authError = __("Por favor faça o login.", true);
            $this->Auth->loginRedirect = array('admin' => true, 'controller' => 'dashboard', 'action' => 'index');
            $this->Auth->logoutRedirect = array('admin' => true, 'controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'login');
            $this->Auth->loginAction = array('admin' => true, 'controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'login');

            // Configurações do usuario logado 
            if ( $this->Auth->user() )
            {           

                $userConditions = array('conditions' => array('User.id' => $this->Auth->user('id')));
                $user = $this->User->find('first', $userConditions);
                $this->set( 'userType', $user['User']['user_type'] );

                if( !$this->Session->check('Admin.last_access') )
                {
                    $last_access = date('Y-m-d h:i:s');
                    $this->User->create(false);
                    $this->User->id = $user['User']['id'];
                    $this->User->save(array('last_access' => $last_access));
                    $this->Session->write('Admin.last_access', $last_access);
                }

                if( !$this->_checkUserPermission( $this->params['controller'], $user, $this->User->blockedControllers ) && $this->params['action'] != 'admin_logout' )  
                {
                    $this->redirect(URL_ADMIN . '/deny');
                }

                $this->set('user', $user);
                if(isset($this->params['pass'][0])) $this->set('edit_id', $this->params['pass'][0]);
                Configure::write('AdminUserId', $user['User']['id']);

            }
            else 
            {
                if ($this->params['action'] != 'admin_login') 
                {
                    $this->redirect(URL_ADMIN . 'users/login');
                }   
            }
            $this->set('utilities', $this->Utility->getAvaliablePlugins($this->params['controller'], $this->params['action']));
        }
        else
        {
            $this->Auth->allow('*');
            $this->_setDefaultContent();
            $this->set('siteConfig', $this->Configuration->findById(1));
            $this->set( 'menuCategories', $this->PostCategory->getCategoriesBySession() );
            $this->set( 'menuPages', $this->Page->getMenuNavigation() );

            // Combinações possíveis para cada categoria nas homes de notícias, formação e agenda. Também em suas categorias.
            $boxCombinationsForHomes = array(
                array(
                    array('startLine' => 1, 'startColumn' => 1, 'boxType' => 2),
                    array('startLine' => 1, 'startColumn' => 3, 'boxType' => 1),
                    array('startLine' => 2, 'startColumn' => 3, 'boxType' => 1),
                    array('startLine' => 1, 'startColumn' => 5, 'boxType' => 0),
                    array('startLine' => 2, 'startColumn' => 5, 'boxType' => 0)
                ),
                array(
                    array('startLine' => 1, 'startColumn' => 1, 'boxType' => 1),
                    array('startLine' => 2, 'startColumn' => 1, 'boxType' => 1),
                    array('startLine' => 1, 'startColumn' => 3, 'boxType' => 0),
                    array('startLine' => 1, 'startColumn' => 4, 'boxType' => 0),
                    array('startLine' => 2, 'startColumn' => 3, 'boxType' => 0),
                    array('startLine' => 2, 'startColumn' => 4, 'boxType' => 0),
                    array('startLine' => 1, 'startColumn' => 5, 'boxType' => 0),
                    array('startLine' => 2, 'startColumn' => 5, 'boxType' => 0)
                )
            );

            $this->set('boxCombinationsForHomes', $boxCombinationsForHomes);
        } 

    }

    /**
     * Pagina de erro
     */
    function cakeError ($type, $options = array()) 
    {
        $this->set('page_name', 'error_page');
        $this->set('title',     __('Página não encontrada', true));
        parent::cakeError($type, $options = array());
    }

    /**
     * Seta dados padroes para ser utilizados no beforeFilter e paginas de erros
     */
    function _setDefaultContent () 
    {

    }

    function beforeRender()
    {
        parent::beforeRender();

        if ($this->_isAdmin()) 
        {
            $userConditions = array('conditions' => array('User.id' => $this->Auth->user('id')));
            $user = $this->User->find('first', $userConditions);


            $this->set( 'menu', $this->AdminMenu->getMenu( $user ) );
            $submenu = ( $this->Session->check(' Admin.Submenu' ) ) ?  $this->Session->read(' Admin.Submenu' ) : $this->AdminMenu->submenu;
            $this->set( 'submenu', $submenu );

            $json_form = array();
            if(!empty($this->data)){
                if(isset($this->data[$this->modelClass])){
                    $json_form = $this->data[$this->modelClass];
                }else{
                    $json_form = $this->data;
                }

                if(isset($this->data['MediaLibrary'])){
                    $json_form['media'] = $this->data['MediaLibrary'];
                }

                $blocked_inputs = array('password');
                foreach ($json_form as $key => $value) {
                    if(in_array($key, $blocked_inputs)){
                        unset($json_form[$key]);
                    }
                }
                $this->set('json_form', $json_form);
            }

        }else{

            $allowed_models = array('Page', 'News', 'Event');
            $view_data = array();
            if (isset($this->viewVars['data']) && !empty($this->viewVars['data'])) {
                foreach ($allowed_models as $key => $model) {
                    if(isset($this->viewVars['data'][$model])){
                        $view_data[$key]['data'] = $this->viewVars['data'][$model];
                    } 
                    if(isset($this->viewVars['data'][$model.'Tag'])){
                        $view_data[$key]['tags'] = $this->viewVars['data'][$model.'Tag'];
                    } 
                }
            }
            $this->set('view_data', $view_data);
        }
    }

    /** 
    *   _isAdmin() : Função usada para verificar se o usuario esta navegando na area de administracao
    *   @return bool
    **/
    function _isAdmin() 
    {
        if (isset($this->params['prefix']) && $this->params['prefix'] == 'admin') {
            return TRUE;
        } 
        else 
        {
            return FALSE;
        }
    }

    /** 
    *   _checkUserPermission() : Função usada para verificar se o usuario esta navegando em uma area permitida
    *   @return bool
    **/

    function _checkUserPermission( $controller, $user, $blockedControllers )
    {   
        $allow = false;
        $permissions = explode( ',', $user['User']['permissions'] );

        if ( in_array( $controller, $permissions ) ) {
            $allow = true;
        }

        if ( in_array( Inflector::classify( $controller ), $blockedControllers ) ) {
            $allow = true;
        }

        return $allow;
    }


    /** 
    *   _createDefaultArchives() : Função usada para criar arquivos nescessarios caso haja um novo controller;
    *   @return bool
    **/
    function _createDefaultArchives($controller)
    {       
        $file_paths = array('js', 'css');
        $file_types = array('js', 'css');

        foreach ($file_types as $key => $type) {        
            $path = APP . WEBROOT_DIR . '/' . ADMIN_CONTENT . '/' . $file_paths[$key] . '/controllers/' . $controller . '.' . $type; 
            $file = new File($path, true, 0777);
            $file->close();
        }
        return true;
    }

    /** 
    *   processAjaxFormData() : Retira os campos vazios do form enviado por ajax
    *   @return $form
    **/
    function processAjaxFormData($form)
    {
        foreach($form as $key => $input){
            if($input == ''){
                unset($form[$key]);
            }
        }
        return $form;
    }

    /**
     * Esta função decide qual o Cookie da sessao utilizar.
     * Deve ser utilizada caso tenha uma area de site e outra de administracao
     * para nao misturar dados.
     * @return void
     */
    function _setCookie() {
        if ($this->_isAdmin()) {
            // admin
            Configure::write('Session.cookie', Configure::read("Session.admin_cookie"));
        }
        else {
            // site
            Configure::write('Session.cookie', Configure::read("Session.site_cookie"));
        }
        // inicia a sessao e ativa ela
        $this->Session->activate();
    }

    /**
     * Função que faz a contabilização do historico de vizualizações de conteudo
     */
    function _setNewViewClick($source_id, $source_table) {

        // Resgato de onde o usuario acessou o post
        $source = (isset($this->params['named']['source'])) ? $this->params['named']['source'] : 'normal';

        // Defino as datas para a busca do registro recente de cliques ( 1 registro novo por hora )
        $dates = array(
            'now'   => date('Y-m-d H:i:s', time()),
            'prev'  => date('Y-m-d H:i:s', (time() - 3600)),
        );

        // Condições para a busca do registro atual de clicks
        $find_options = array(
            'conditions' => array(
                'ViewClick.source'          => $source,
                'ViewClick.source_id'       => $source_id,
                'ViewClick.source_table'    => $source_table,
                'ViewClick.created BETWEEN "' . $dates['prev'] . '" AND "' . $dates['now'] .'"'
        ));

        // Variaveis default para serem salvos
        $new_views = 1;
        $data = array();

        // Caso haja um registro atual, atualizo este registro somando + 1 click ou crio um novo registro com 1 click computado
        if ($actual = $this->ViewClick->find('first', $find_options)){
            $new_views = $actual['ViewClick']['views'] + 1;
            $this->ViewClick->create(false);
            $this->ViewClick->id = $actual['ViewClick']['id'];
        } else {

            $data['source']         = $source;
            $data['source_id']      = $source_id;
            $data['source_table']   = $source_table;
        }

        // Salvo os dados na base
        $data['views'] = $new_views;
        $this->ViewClick->save($data);  
    }       



    /**
     * Função que resgata os dados nescessarios para o funcionamento do elemento last_posts
     */
    public function _setLastPostsElementData($used_ids = array())
    {

        // Resgato Ultimas Noticias
        $last_news_conditions = array('News.status' => 1);
        if(isset($used_ids['News'])) $last_news_conditions[] = 'News.id NOT IN (' . implode(',', array_unique($used_ids['News'])) . ')';
        $last_news = $this->News->find( 'all', array( 
            'limit' => 9,
            'order' => 'News.date DESC',
            'conditions' => $last_news_conditions
            )
        );

        // Restado ultimos Artigo e Entrevista
        $last_articles_conditions = array('ArticleInterview.status' => 1);
        if(isset($used_ids['ArticleInterview'])) $last_articles_conditions[] = 'ArticleInterview.id NOT IN (' . implode(',', array_unique($used_ids['ArticleInterview'])) . ')';
        $last_articles = $this->ArticleInterview->find( 'all', array( 
            'limit' => 9,
            'order' => 'ArticleInterview.date DESC',
            'conditions' => $last_articles_conditions
            )
        );

        // Proximos Eventos
        $next_events = $this->Event->find( 'all', array( 
            'limit' => 9,
            'order' => 'Event.date ASC',
            'conditions' => array(
                'Event.status' => 1,
                'Event.date >= CURDATE()',
            ))
        );

        // Seto as variaves para a view
        $this->set('last_news', $last_news);
        $this->set('last_articles', $last_articles);
        $this->set('next_events', $next_events);
    }


    /**
     *  Função que resgata as infos nescessarias para o elemento de noticias
    */
    public function _setNewsElementData($used_ids = array())
    {

        $news = array();

        // Datas para as condiçoes das buscas de cada periodo
        $dates = array(
            'now'   => date('Y-m-d H:i:s', time()),
            'today'  => date('Y-m-d H:i:s', (time() - 86400)),
            'week'  => date('Y-m-d H:i:s', (time() - 602280)),
            'month'  => date('Y-m-d H:i:s', (time() - 18068400)),
        );

        // Ligo o modelo de historico de clicks com a tabela de noticias
        $bind = array('belongsTo' => array('News' => array('foreignKey' => 'source_id', 'className' => 'News')));
        $this->ViewClick->bindModel($bind, false);


        // Condições para o periodo de 24h <-> Agora
        $today_options = array(
            'conditions' => array(
                'ViewClick.source' => 'normal',
                'ViewClick.source_table' => 'News',
                'ViewClick.created BETWEEN "' . $dates['today'] . '" AND "' . $dates['now'] .'"'
            ), 'order' => array('ViewClick.views DESC')
        );
        $news['today'] = $this->ViewClick->find('all', $today_options);

        // Condições para o periodo de 1 Semana <-> Agora
        $week_options = array(
            'conditions' => array(
                'ViewClick.source' => 'normal',
                'ViewClick.source_table' => 'News',
                'ViewClick.created BETWEEN "' . $dates['week'] . '" AND "' . $dates['now'] .'"'
            ), 'order' => array('ViewClick.views DESC')
        );
        $news['week'] = $this->ViewClick->find('all', $week_options);

        // Condições para o periodo de 1 Mês <-> Agora
        $month_options = array(
            'conditions' => array(
                'ViewClick.source' => 'normal',
                'ViewClick.source_table' => 'News',
                'ViewClick.created BETWEEN "' . $dates['month'] . '" AND "' . $dates['now'] .'"'
            ), 'order' => array('ViewClick.views DESC')
        );
        $news['month'] = $this->ViewClick->find('all', $month_options);

        // Condições para ultimas noticias, eliminando noticias que ja sejam destaques
        $last_news_conditions = array('News.status' => 1);
        if(isset($used_ids['News'])) $last_news_conditions[] = 'News.id NOT IN (' . implode(',', array_unique($used_ids['News'])) . ')';

        // Resgato as Ultimas noticias
        $last_news = $this->News->find( 'all', array( 
            'limit' => 9,
            'order' => 'News.date DESC',
            'conditions' => $last_news_conditions
            )
        );

        // Seto variaveis para view
        $this->set('news', $news); 
        $this->set('last_news', $last_news); 
    }

    public function _setArticlesInterviewsElementData($used_ids = array())
    {

        $articles = array();    
        // Datas para as condiçoes das buscas de cada periodo
        $dates = array(
            'now'   => date('Y-m-d H:i:s', time()),
            'today'  => date('Y-m-d H:i:s', (time() - 86400)),
            'week'  => date('Y-m-d H:i:s', (time() - 602280)),
            'month'  => date('Y-m-d H:i:s', (time() - 18068400)),
        );

        // Ligo o modelo de historico de clicks com a tabela de artigos
        $bind = array('belongsTo' => array('ArticleInterview' => array('foreignKey' => 'source_id', 'className' => 'ArticleInterview')));
        $this->ViewClick->bindModel($bind, false);

        // Condições para o periodo de 24h <-> Agora
        $today_options = array(
            'conditions' => array(
                'ViewClick.source' => 'normal',
                'ViewClick.source_table' => 'ArticleInterview',
                'ViewClick.created BETWEEN "' . $dates['today'] . '" AND "' . $dates['now'] .'"'
            ), 'order' => array('ViewClick.views DESC')
        );
        $articles['today'] = $this->ViewClick->find('all', $today_options);

        // Condições para o periodo de 1 Semana <-> Agora
        $week_options = array(
            'conditions' => array(
                'ViewClick.source' => 'normal',
                'ViewClick.source_table' => 'ArticleInterview',
                'ViewClick.created BETWEEN "' . $dates['week'] . '" AND "' . $dates['now'] .'"'
            ), 'order' => array('ViewClick.views DESC')
        );
        $articles['week'] = $this->ViewClick->find('all', $week_options);

        // Condições para o periodo de 1 Mês <-> Agora
        $month_options = array(
            'conditions' => array(
                'ViewClick.source' => 'normal',
                'ViewClick.source_table' => 'ArticleInterview',
                'ViewClick.created BETWEEN "' . $dates['month'] . '" AND "' . $dates['now'] .'"'
            ), 'order' => array('ViewClick.views DESC')
        );
        $articles['month'] = $this->ViewClick->find('all', $month_options);

        // Condições para ultimos artigos, eliminando artigos que ja sejam destaques
        $last_articles_conditions = array('ArticleInterview.status' => 1, 'ArticleInterview.author_id' => 0);
        if(isset($used_ids['ArticleInterview'])) $last_articles_conditions[] = 'ArticleInterview.id NOT IN (' . implode(',', array_unique($used_ids['ArticleInterview'])) . ')';

        // Resgato as Ultimos Artigos
        $last_articles = $this->ArticleInterview->find( 'all', array( 
            'limit' => 4,
            'order' => 'ArticleInterview.date DESC',
            'conditions' => $last_articles_conditions
            )
        );

        // Seto variaveis para view
        $this->set('articles', $articles); 
        $this->set('last_articles', $last_articles); 
    }

    /**
     * Retorna ultimo tweet
     */
    function get_last_tweet () 
    {
        $this->autoRender = false;

        Cache::set(array('duration' => '+20 minutes'));
        if (Cache::read('last_tweet')) 
        {
            Cache::set(array('duration' => '+20 minutes'));
            echo Cache::read('last_tweet');
        }
        else 
        {
            $site_config = $this->Configuration->findById(1);
            $data = $this->Twitter->getLastTweet('juventudeomi');
            if (isset($data[0]) && !empty($data[0])) 
            {
                Cache::write('last_tweet', ($data[0]['text']));
                echo ($data[0]['text']);
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Resgata cep
     */
    public function cep ($cep = null) 
    {
        $this->autoRender = false;
        $data = $this->Cep->getDataCep($cep);
        echo json_encode($data);
    }
}
```

E a minha view eu acho que é essa:

```
<div class="container center">
<div class="group index">
        <?php 
            if ( isset( $features ) ) {
                foreach ( $features as $key => $feature ) {         

                    $featureClasses = 'tile ';
                    $featureClasses .= ( isset( $feature['Feature']['classes'] ) ) ? $feature['Feature']['classes'] . ' ' : ' ';
                    $featureClasses .= ( isset( $feature['Feature']['source_table'] ) ) ? $translate->sourceClass( $feature['Feature']['source_table'] ) . ' ' : ' ';
                    ?>
                    <div class="<?php echo $featureClasses ?>" data-start-column="<?php echo $feature['Feature']['start_column'] ?>" data-start-line="<?php echo $feature['Feature']['start_line'] ?>" data-position="<?php echo $feature['Feature']['position'] ?>">
                        <?php if ( $feature['Feature']['source_table'] != 'Widget' ) { ?>

                            <a target="<?php echo ( $feature['Feature']['source_table'] != 'link' ) ? '_self' : '_blank';  ?>" href="<?php echo ( $feature['Feature']['source_table'] != 'link' ) ? $this->base : '' ?><?php echo $feature['Feature']['link'] ?>">
                                <?php 
                                    if ( !empty( $feature['Feature']['image_id'] ) ) { 
                                        $title = $viewFn->getImageTitle( $feature['MediaLibrary']['html_title'], $feature['Feature']['title'] );
                                ?>  
                                        <img src="<?php echo $this->base . '/' . $feature['Feature']['image_path'] ?>" alt="<?php echo $title ?>" title="<?php echo $title ?>" />
                                <?php } ?>

                                <div class="text">
                                    <h3>

                                        <strong><?php echo $feature['Feature']['title'] ?></strong>
                                        <?php  
                                            echo ( !empty( $feature['Feature']['sub_title'] ) ) ? '<span class="subtitle">' . $feature['Feature']['sub_title'] . '</span>' : '';
                                        ?>
                                    </h3>
                                </div>
                                <?php if ( isset( $feature['Feature']['comments_number'] ) ) : ?>
                                    <p class="comments"><?php echo $feature['Feature']['comments_number'] ?> comentário<?php echo ( $feature['Feature']['comments_number'] > 1 ) ? 's' : ''; ?>
                                </p>
                                <?php endif ?>      
                                <span class="icon"></span>
                            </a>
                        <?php 

                            } else { 

                                if ( !empty( $feature['Feature']['video_id'] ) ) {
                                    $dataWidget['widget_video'] = $feature;
                                }

                                echo $this->element( $feature['Feature']['widget'], array( 'dataWidget' => $dataWidget ) ); 
                            } 
                         ?> 
                    </div>
                    <?php
                    if ( in_array( ($key+1), $painelConfig ) ) {
                        echo '</div> <div class="group index">';
                    }
                }
            }
        ?>
    </div>
    <div class="group index">
        <?php
        $startColumn = 1;
        // notícias
        if ( count( $featuresNewsList ) ) {
            ?>
            <div class="tile col3 row4 customPosts" data-start-column="<?php echo $startColumn; ?>" data-start-line="1">
                <div class="posts news">
                    <div class="title">
                        <h3>Notícias</h3>
                        <div class="bar"></div>
                        <span class="icon"></span>
                    </div>
                    <?php
                    for ( $i = 1; $i <= 3; $i++ ) {
                        if ( isset( $featuresNewsList[$i] ) ) {
                            $feature = $featuresNewsList[$i]['Feature'];
                            $featureNews = $featuresNewsList[$i]['News'];
                            ?>
                            <div class="item <?php if ( $i == 1 ) { ?>first<?php } ?>">
                                <?php
                                $link = substr( URL , 0, -1) . $feature['link'];
                                if ( $feature['image_path'] ) {
                                    ?>
                                    <div class="image">
                                        <a href="<?php echo $link; ?>"><img src="<?php echo $feature['image_path']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $feature['title']; ?>" title="<?php echo $feature['title']; ?>" /></a>
                                    </div>
                                    <?php
                                }
                                ?>
                                <h4><a href="<?php echo $link; ?>"><?php echo $feature['title']; ?></a></h4>
                                <p><?php echo $time->format( 'd/m/Y', $featureNews['created'] ) ?> - Atualizado em <?php echo $time->format( 'd/m/Y H:i', $featureNews['modified'] ) ?></p>
                            </div>
                            <?php
                        } else {
                            ?>
                            <div class="item"></div>
                            <?php
                        }
                    }
                    ?>
                </div>
            </div>
            <?php
            $startColumn = $startColumn + 3;
        }
        ?>

        <?php
        //formação
        if ( count( $featuresArticleInterviewList ) ) {
            ?>
            <div class="tile col3 row4 customPosts" data-start-column="<?php echo $startColumn; ?>" data-start-line="1">
                <div class="posts formation">
                    <div class="title">
                        <h3>Formação</h3>
                        <div class="bar"></div>
                        <span class="icon"></span>
                    </div>
                    <?php
                    for ( $i = 1; $i <= 3; $i++ ) {
                        if ( isset( $featuresArticleInterviewList[$i] ) ) {
                            $feature = $featuresArticleInterviewList[$i]['Feature'];
                            $featureArticleInterview = $featuresArticleInterviewList[$i]['ArticleInterview'];
                            ?>
                            <div class="item <?php if ( $i == 1 ) { ?>first<?php } ?>">
                                <?php
                                $link = substr( URL , 0, -1) . $feature['link'];
                                if ( $feature['image_path'] ) {
                                    ?>
                                    <div class="image">
                                        <a href="<?php echo $link; ?>"><img src="<?php echo $feature['image_path']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $feature['title']; ?>" title="<?php echo $feature['title']; ?>" /></a>
                                    </div>
                                    <?php
                                }
                                ?>
                                <h4><a href="<?php echo $link; ?>"><?php echo $feature['title']; ?></a></h4>
                                <p><?php echo $time->format( 'd/m/Y', $featureArticleInterview['date'] ); ?></p>
                            </div>
                            <?php
                        } else {
                            ?>
                            <div class="item"></div>
                            <?php
                        }
                    }
                    ?>
                </div>
            </div>
            <?php
            $startColumn = $startColumn + 3;
        }
        ?>

        <?php
        // agenda
        if ( count( $featuresEventList ) ) {
            ?>
            <div class="tile col2 row4 customPosts" data-start-column="<?php echo $startColumn; ?>" data-start-line="1">
                <div class="posts agenda">
                    <div class="title">
                        <h3>Agenda</h3>
                        <div class="bar"></div>
                        <span class="icon"></span>
                    </div>
                    <?php
                    for ( $i = 1; $i <= 2; $i++ ) {
                        if ( isset( $featuresEventList[$i] ) ) {
                            $feature = $featuresEventList[$i]['Feature'];
                            $featureEvent = $featuresEventList[$i]['Event'];
                            ?>
                            <div class="item <?php if ( $i == 1 ) { ?>first<?php } ?>">
                                <?php
                                $link = substr( URL , 0, -1) . $feature['link'];
                                if ( $feature['image_path'] ) {
                                    ?>
                                    <div class="image">
                                        <a href="<?php echo $link; ?>"><img src="<?php echo $feature['image_path']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $feature['title']; ?>" title="<?php echo $feature['title']; ?>" /></a>
                                    </div>
                                    <?php
                                }
                                ?>
                                <h4><a href="<?php echo $link; ?>"><?php echo $feature['title']; ?></a></h4>
                                <p><?php echo $time->format( 'd', $featureEvent['date'] ); ?> de <?php echo $timeFn->getFullMonth( $featureEvent['date'] ); ?> de <?php echo $time->format( 'Y', $featureEvent['date'] ); ?></p>
                            </div>
                            <?php
                        } /*else {
                            ?>
                            <div class="item"></div>
                            <?php
                        }*/
                    }
                    ?>

                </div>
            </div>
            <?php
        }
        ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: você só postou uma linha, o erro diz que a variável não esta definida, não tem como saber da onde vem a variável do jeito que você colocou o código, posta aonde você declara essa variavel. Posta o controlador e o view (se necessário o model, eu não sei como o cakephp funciona ao certo).

Comment: Vê se melhorou, @GuilhermeNascimento

Comment: `$sitesConfig` é uma variável sua ou do cake? nesse código ai ela não aparece definida, ela tem cara de conter a raiz do projeto é usada p montar os link de imagens algo assim.

Comment: O que me deixa mais grilado é que o site está funcionando perfeitamente em http://arqrio.org  
Os dois estão no mesmo servidor. Eu apenas fiz o download e upload dos arquivos. Pesquisei o SiteConfig no projeto e não encontrei.
@rray

Comment: Baixou via ftp? as vezes o arquivo vai ou vem zicado, aí vc tem uns problemas estranhos ...

Comment: Sim.
Vou tentar baixar de novo para ver se resolve.

Comment: Acho que deve encerrar.
Isso está ocorrendo todas as vezes que tento abrir uma página que não existe.